# If $G = HK$ is a Frobenius group with the complement $H$ being maximal, then $K$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be some finite Frobenius group with Frobenius complement $H$ and kernel $K$. I want to show that if $H$ is a maximal subgroup in $G$, then $K$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group.

This is an exercise from the book *Theory of Finite Groups* by Kurzweil and Stellmacher, appearing after the fourth chapter.

*My attempts*: By maximality of $H$ the action on its coset space is primitive, and $K$ must act transitive. Also it must act regular as $K$ fixes no coset, so I can deduce that $K$ must be minimal normal in $G$. So, if I can establish that $K$ is abelian or that it has some abelian minimal normal subgroup itself I would be done. I have a proof if the order of $H$ is even, by looking how an involution of $H$ would act on $K$, but I cannot find an argument if $H$ contains no involution. So any ideas how to tackle this case?

Comment: I'd be really surprised if you could get this without using Thompson's theorem...

Comment: Can you use the idea that, if $K$ is not abelian, then its derived subgroup $K^\prime$, together with $H$, generates a proper subgroup of $G$ properly containing $H$; i.e., $H < K^{\prime}H < G$, contradicting maximality of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: @James That just proves that $K'=K$. But if the result was wrong then $K$ would be a direct product of isomorphic nonabelian simple groups, so it would be perfect.

Comment: @DerekHolt But a Frobenius kernel is non-trivial and nilpotent, so it cannot be perfect.

Comment: @James Yes of course, but I was assuming that one was expected to solve this problem without using Thompson's result on the nilpotency of the Frobenius kernel. If you are use that then the problem is easy.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm sure you're right.  I don't have the book to see what is available for the exercise, which is why I framed my suggestion as a question.

Comment: @James Yes, this result is not introduced in any chapter before this exercise, and a footnote mentiones that normality could be used, but does not mention nilpotency. So it should be solved without that. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling to solve this, but after looking at the results in the book about Frobenius groups I realized that it can be done using  4.1.8 (a) from the book.

You have proved that $K$ must be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$, and if $K$ is abelian then you are done. Also if $K$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$ then $Z(K) \lhd G$, so $K=Z(K)$ and we are done.

Now let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(K)$ for some prime $p$ dividing $|K|$, and let $N = N_G(P)$. Then by the Frattini Argument $G = KN$, so $|N| = |N \cap K||G|/|K| = |N \cap K||H|$. Note also that, since $K \ne P$, we cannot have $N=G$ since that would contradict the minimality of $K$ as a normal subgroup of $G$.

We now apply 4.1.8 (a) in the book to the subgroup $N=U$. If $N \cap H^x = 1$ for all $x$, then $N \le K$, which is false because $|N| = |N \cap K||H|$ and $|H|>1$. So there exists $x \in G$ with $|N \cap H^x|>1$ and, since $1 \ne P \le N$, we do not have $N \le H^x$. So $N$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $N \cap K$ and complement $H_0$, where $H_0$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $H$.

So $|N| = |N \cap K||H_0|$ and hence $|H|=|H_0|$ so $H_0$ is equal to a conjugate of $H$, which contradicts the maximality of $H$ (and hence also of all of its conjugates) in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Btw in your 2nd paragraph I guess you mean $K$ instead of $P$ in "if $P$ is a $p$-group [...]".

Comment: Yes - corrected!